# Execute Stored Procedure or Dynamic SQL in a Function

Tags: sql-server, function, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql, sqlclr

I am using SQL Server 2012 and am trying to convert data in a temp table to another temp table, converting values as I copy the info from one table to another.  Here is an example of the input table:

```
#IMPORT_DATA
SSN             Plan                          StartDate
123-45-6789     Basic Life Insurance          1/1/2015
123-45-6789     Vision                        1/1/2015
123-45-6789     Dental                        1/1/2015
```

I need to convert this data to something like this:

```
#STAGE_DATA
SSN             Plan                          StartDate
123456789       BLI                           20150101
123456789       VIS                           20150101
123456789       DTL                           20150101
```

I have a translation table that defines a SQL script that will convert the data but am having an issue with executing dynamic SQL from within a function.

I am using a table-valued function to load `#STAGE_DATA`, passing in the `#IMPORT_DATA` as XML.  The table function is:

```sql
create function dcBPI.TranslateBenefitsStagingTable_FN
(
      @XmlData xml
    , @TranslationType varchar(50)
    , @Company varchar(3) = null
)
returns @ReturnTable table (
      [RowID] [int]
    , [SSN] [varchar](9) NULL
    , [Plan] [varchar](3) NULL
    , [StartDate] [varchar](8) NULL
)
as

begin

    insert into @ReturnTable ([RowID], [EmpSSN]) 
    select [Table].[Column].value('ID[1]', '[int]') as 'RowID'   -- no translation for RowID
            , dcBPI.TranslateSourceValue_FN('Benefit', 'SSN', [Table].[Column].value('SSN[1]', '[varchar](11)'), @Company) as 'SSN'
            , dcBPI.TranslateSourceValue_FN('Benefit', 'Plan', [Table].[Column].value('Plan[1]', ' [varchar](3)'), @Company) as 'Plan'
            , dcBPI.TranslateSourceValue_FN('Benefit', 'StartDate', [Table].[Column].value('StartDate[1]', ' [varchar](10)'), @Company) as 'StartDate'

    from @XmlData.nodes('//row') as [Table]([Column])

    return 
end
go
```

The translation function is:

```sql
create function dcBPI.TranslateSourceValue_FN
(
      @TranslationType varchar(50)
    , @DestinationHeader varchar(255)
    , @SourceValue varchar(255)
    , @Company varchar(3) = null
)
returns varchar(255)
as
begin
    declare   @DestinationValue varchar(255) = 'Missing'
            , @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

    if len(rtrim(@Company)) = 0 set @Company = null

    select  @sql = 
            select
                    distinct td.DestinationValue
            from    dcBPI.TranslationData td    
            where   (
                        td.Company = @Company 
                        or td.Company = 'All'
                    )
                    and td.TranslationType = @TranslationType
                    and td.DestinationHeader = @DestinationHeader
                    and td.SourceValue = @SourceValue

    )

    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@OutputValue nvarchar(max) OUTPUT', @OutputValue = @DestinationValue OUTPUT

    return @DestinationValue

end
go
```

When I execute the table-valued function (which in turn executes `TranslateSourceValue_FN`), I get an error message of:

> Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed
>   from within a function.

I know from other articles that I cannot call Dynamic SQL from a function, so is there another way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

**EDIT** (added @sql examples)
The SQL that is to be used are simple select statements like:

- `select replace('123-45-6789' '-', '')`
- `select PlanCode from CodeTable where Plan = @Plan'`

Comment: @srutzky See edit for `@sql` examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just need to execute some dynamic SQL, and that Dynamic SQL is simple SELECT statement, you can use the following SQLCLR code to replace your call to `sp_excutesql` with just:

```sql
SET @DestinationValue = dbo.SimpleSelect(@sql);
```

The C# code for this simple function is:

```cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public class TheFunction
{
    [return: SqlFacet(MaxSize = 4000)]
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read,
        SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read)]
    public static SqlString SimpleSelect(
        [SqlFacet(MaxSize = 4000)] SqlString TheQuery)
    {
        string _Output = null;

        if (TheQuery.Value.Trim() == String.Empty)
        {
            return new SqlString(_Output);
        }

        using (SqlConnection _Connection =
            new SqlConnection("Context Connection = true;"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand _Command = _Connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                _Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                _Command.CommandText = TheQuery.Value;

                _Connection.Open();
                _Output = _Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
        }

        return new SqlString(_Output);
    }
}
```

Because it uses the in-process Context Connection, the Assembly can remain marked as `SAFE` and the database does *not* need to be set to `TRUSTWORTHY ON`. But it also means that you are bound by all of the other restrictions that T-SQL functions have, things like: can't use `NEWID()`, can't change the state of the database, can't use `RAISERROR` or `SET` statements, etc.

The following code is the T-SQL wrapper object that references the C# method shown above. Please note the `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` at the end of the 2nd line. This is *not* something that Visual Studio / SSDT allows you to set, so it must be done manually by running the code below.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SimpleSelect](@TheQuery [nvarchar](4000))
RETURNS [nvarchar](4000) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER, RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS EXTERNAL NAME [DynamicSqlForFunctions].[TheFunction].[SimpleSelect];
```

**EXAMPLES**

1. The following two examples both return `NULL`. Please note that the first example shown passes in a `NULL`, and there is no handling for `TheQuery.IsNull` in the C# method, yet there is no "Object not set to a reference..." error. That is all thanks to the magic of the `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` option specified in the `CREATE FUNCTION`.

   ```sql
   SELECT dbo.SimpleSelect(NULL);
   -- NULL

   SELECT dbo.SimpleSelect('');
   -- NULL
   ```
2. The following example shows that you can select pretty much any data type and are not required to covert it to `NVARCHAR` in order to have it work.

   ```sql
   SELECT dbo.SimpleSelect('SELECT GETDATE();');
   -- 10/12/2015 10:25:33 AM
   ```
3. The following shows passing in a multi-statement query:

   ```sql
   DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000);
   SET @SQL = N'
   DECLARE @TempSum INT;
   SET @TempSum = 0;
   SELECT TOP(80) @TempSum = so.[object_id]
   FROM   [master].[sys].[objects] so
   SELECT @TempSum;
   ';

   SELECT dbo.SimpleSelect(@SQL);
   -- 133575514
   ```
4. The following example shows that we can execute a simple, read-only Stored Procedure via this Function. That is not something that can be done in a T-SQL Function. But, like T-SQL Functions, it cannot run side-effecting statements, which is why there is no `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in the Stored Procedure.

   So first run this:

   ```sql
   CREATE PROCEDURE #SimpleProcTest
   AS
   SELECT TOP(5) so.[name], so.[type_desc]
   FROM   [master].[sys].[objects] so
   ORDER BY so.[name] ASC;
   GO
   ```

   Then, if you want to test it, run this:

   ```sql
   EXEC #SimpleProcTest;
   ```

   Finally, here we do the full test which includes creating a table variable, dumping the results of the Stored Procedure into that table variable.

   ```sql
   DECLARE @TestSQL NVARCHAR(4000) = N'
   DECLARE @Bob TABLE (
   [name] sysname,
   [type_desc] NVARCHAR(60)
   );

   INSERT INTO @Bob
      EXEC #SimpleProcTest;

   SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM @Bob
   WHERE PATINDEX(N''%[0-9]%'', [name]) > 0;
   ';

   SELECT dbo.SimpleSelect(@TestSQL);
   -- 2
   ```
5. And for the last example, we see again that we are bound by most of the same restrictions that T-SQL Functions have placed on them.

   ```sql
   SELECT dbo.SimpleSelect('SELECT NEWID();');
   -- Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
   -- Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'SELECT WITHOUT QUERY' within a function.
   ```